# Is it possible to view files stored in iCloud Backup?

Tags: icloud

I have a backup for my iPhone 5s from January. Is there any way I can download them onto my computer ?

[image]

Is there any way I can look into the files that were backed up onto iCloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No and no, I'm afraid,

You could restore the iCloud backup to the device, then back it up to the computer and use a 3rd party tool to dig into that backup file, but you won't be able to get at the iCloud backup contents directly.

Comment: I've found a third party solution for now.