# View iOS Health data externally

Tags: ios, icloud, health-kit

Is there a way to view ios 8 health data externally?  For example, with iCloud sync it seems feasible to be able to access the data through a website (i've checked `https://www.icloud.com/` but it's not visible).  I really like the Health app dashboard but I'd like it more if I could also see it from other devices :)

If there is no official way, does Apple allow accessing iCloud data through some web API?  I can build a proof-of-concept dashboard if they have some kind of web service.

Lastly, another method I've considered is building an app that (after requesting permissions) reads the data through HealthKit and then provides that to an external storage service.  I'd like to know if something like this exists (so I don't reinvent the wheel).

---

I found [another thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/133145/109948) from *June 2014* that indicates it's not possible to directly inspect iCloud backups, though I'm pretty sure they're only referring to viewing through iTunes or iCloud.com.

Comment: I think Apple wants you to know your health data is save and personal and therefor does not store it on 'their' servers, but only let the data live on 'your' device. You could write a program that accesses your health kit data by your approval and than let that program export your data to an json/xml/csv file... Good idea :) I'll start coding right away!

Answer (score 6):

Best way I found was to:
Open Health App and head to **Health data** < **All** and use the arrow on the upper right of the screen then choose *Export*.

It will take a while if you have a data. You'll be able to get a ZIP file that you can mail to yourself.

Just use **[XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)** and you should (at least!) be able to read your data. You could then use dropbox to sync it with your other devices.

[image: iOS iPhone screenhost]
[image: Xcode export.xml example]

Comment: Can this exported data be imported on another iOS device?

Comment: Not sure but there is now another app you can use to export the data called QS Access: https://appsto.re/ca/ocQ22.i The file will be available as a CSV or as a board.

Comment: Xcode is overkill for reading an XML file -- just grab a copy of Sublime Text and it will be much faster to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

Doing an **en**crypted backup on iTunes (unencrypted backups don't include health datas) and using a backup reader app, like **iBackupbot** (http://download.cnet.com/iBackupBot/3000-18553_4-75532275.html), that will ask you your backup password, you can get on your computer the healthdata folder which contains all your Health datas!

[image: HealthData folder]

Comment: and is this data still readable?

Comment: They're sqlite databases, I haven't any program to read it... but are 16mb of datas so there should be something!

Comment: you do have a program to read it. OS X has sqlite installed by default.  `/usr/bin/sqlite3`

Comment: I have no idea on how to use it!

Comment: @Matte.Car do you mean an __unencrypted__ backup? an encrypted backup shouldn't be readable without the encryption keys

Comment: nono encrypted! Then iBackupbot will ask you your password to read it. In unencrypted backups health datas and password weren't saved!

Answer (score 5):

I created a webapp to convert the exported XML file from the Apple Health app to an easy to use comma-separated file.

-> http://ericwolter.com/projects/health-export.html