# How do I view the lifetime total from the Health app?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app, health-kit

Is it possible to see the lifetime totals (steps, distance, etc) from all data in the Health app? Perhaps with a third party app?

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer: I recently released a new app that displays your (lifetime) Apple Health and workouts data.*

The app is called “Health Stats”. Health Stats is a free app (with a one-time premium in-app purchase) that allows you to easily view your health, activity and workout data from the Apple Health app. You can view this data for different date ranges such as: lifetime, this week, this month or set a custom date range yourself.

You can download the app here: https://apps.apple.com/app/health-stats/id1543220823

Health Stats currently supports the following health and workout data sets:

General data sets:

- Total exercise time
- Total step count
- Total walking and running distance
- Total flights of stairs climbed
- Total stand time
- Total stand hours (hours in which you've stood and moved for at least 1 minute)
- Total wheelchair pushes
- Total wheelchair distance
- Active energy burned
- Resting energy burned
- Total energy burned

Workout data sets:

- Total workout time
- Total workout distance
- Total workouts
- Running workouts (time, distance, energy burned and count)
- Walking workouts (time, distance, energy burned and count)
- Cycling workouts (time, distance, energy burned and count)
- Swimming workouts (time, distance, energy burned, swimming strokes and count)
- Elliptical workouts (time, energy burned and count)
- HIIT workouts (time, energy burned and count)
- Strength workouts (time, energy burned and count)
- Skiing workouts (time, distance, energy burned and count)
- Snowboarding workouts (time, distance, energy burned and count)
- Hiking workouts (time, distance, energy burned and count)

Note: all data is directly received from the Apple Health app and none of it will ever leave the iPhone or is stored elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the disclaimer and comprehensive answer. I wish you success with your app and thanks for contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not possible anymore with iOS 10 to export your health data, you can export and view it with this app:
QS Access by Quantified Self Labs
https://appsto.re/de/ocQ22.i

Comment: That's very painful though. Surely if a third party app has access to the full Health data it can add up the totals. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That's true. QS access only displays your data and can export it.

Do you want to view your lifetime totals on a regular basis on your iPhone? In this case there is a two step solution possible using workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I typically export all the data which makes a zip file of the xml data and then send it to a file storage / web application to analyze / summarize the data.

- [View iOS Health data externally](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167671/view-ios-health-data-externally)

The thread above has some web apps and options to use Xcode or other editors and tools to process the exported data. I’m not aware of a way to do this on iOS, but if I do or someone else does, we can edit this answer later.